# JSch sftp file upload in android application

Tags: android, ssh, sftp, jsch

I am trying to upload a file which is having 500 KB size to SFTP server using JSch library from my android application. But it's not uploading the file into the server if it is greater than 2KB size. Also it is not throwing any error or exception.

Note: I am able to upload the same 500 KB file from FileZilla and WinSCP Desktop Client to the SFTP server. Also I am able to upload the same file to the SFTP server using JSch lib from my Java app without any issues.

Please see the code snippet below: (The same code I used for my Android & Java application).

```
            JSch jsch = new JSch();

            session = jsch.getSession(SFTP_USER, SFTP_HOST, SFT_PORT);
            session.setPassword(SFTP_PASS);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications",
                    "password");
            session.connect();
            channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
            File file = new File(DirectoryUtils.getCacheDir(context), fileName);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

            channelSftp.put(fis, file.getName());
            fis.close();
```

So, somebody please help me to solve this issue or tell me is there any file size configuration needed to specify in tje ssh server.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the `FileInputStream` read to the end? Do you have an access to server-side logs? Anything useful there? [Enable JSch logging](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Logger.java.html) and show us the log.

Comment: Hi Martin Prikryl, we were trying to print the JSch logging but there were no logs available.